# genserver implementation to open redis state

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I want to open a Redis connection and I have written a code something like this for persistent connection within the system. The way I'm doing this I'm calling a handle_info function which uses the Redix client. I have defined the dependency for redix

```
def start_link(opts \\ [name: __MODULE__]) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, Keyword.merge(opts, name: __MODULE__))
  end

  @impl true
  def init(_) do
    send(self(), :connect)
    {:ok, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:connect, _conn) do
    host = "redis://localhost:6379/3"

    case Redix.start_link(host) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        IO.inspect(conn)
        Process.monitor(conn.pid)
        {:noreply, conn}

      {:error, _} ->
       
        Process.send_after(self(), :connect, @reconnect_interval)
        {:noreply, nil}
    end
  end
```

I call with redix client to the server with handle info. When I use the PID to set a key in Redis
something like this

```
Redix.command!(conn, ["SET", "queue"])
```

I get this error

```
    [error] GenServer Zuppler.Utils.Redis.Connection terminating
** (RuntimeError) attempted to cast GenServer Zuppler.Utils.Redis.Connection but no handle_cast/2 clause was provided
    (zuppler_utils 0.1.12) lib/gen_server.ex:824: Zuppler.Utils.Redis.Connection.handle_cast/2
    (stdlib 3.17.1) gen_server.erl:695: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib 3.17.1) gen_server.erl:771: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib 3.17.1) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", {:pipeline, [["llen", "list_name"]], {#PID<0.694.0>, #Reference<0.884395455.1828454401.122583>}, 5000}}
State: #PID<0.801.0>
** (EXIT from #PID<0.694.0>) shell process exited with reason: an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) attempted to cast GenServer Zuppler.Utils.Redis.Connection but no handle_cast/2 clause was provided
        (zuppler_utils 0.1.12) lib/gen_server.ex:824: Zuppler.Utils.Redis.Connection.handle_cast/2
        (stdlib 3.17.1) gen_server.erl:695: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
        (stdlib 3.17.1) gen_server.erl:771: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
        (stdlib 3.17.1) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have `IO.inspect(conn)` which must have shown you `conn` **is a `pid`**. Right in the next line you try to call `conn.pid` which is treated as a function call, which maps to `:erlang.apply(#PID<0.1075.0>, :pid, [])` and obviously raises. The following would most likely do.

```
- Process.monitor(conn.pid)
+ Process.monitor(conn)
```

---

*Sidenote:* use [`GenServer.handle_continue/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_continue/2) callback instead of sending the message to `self` which exists for exactly this kind of initialization.

Also, one usually starts `Redix` within the application supervision tree as described in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/redix/real-world-usage.html#content).

Comment: handle_continue giving me an error. I will add that above

Comment: If you want to get the help, please consider putting more effort into the problem description: post your code that produced an error alongside with the error itself.

Comment: I've updated the description please check